# Solution: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method isCtrlPressed(Landroid/view/KeyEvent;) OR (Landroid/support/v4/view/KeyEventCompat)

Tags: java, android, crash, android-support-library

As I had problems with

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method isCtrlPressed(Landroid/view/KeyEvent;)
```

and with

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/view/KeyEventCompat
```

I wanted to help u and show u how i managed to solve these problems.

**I use:**

```
 compileSdkVersion 27
 minSdkVersion 21
 targetSdkVersion 27
 versionName '2.6'
 versionCode 8
 buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
```

I needed just to remove all old support dependencies from the gradle (for example: com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0).
And then add those two lines:

```
- implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'

- implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
```

Comment: Post the solution as an answer and then accept it. Also, this is probably a duplicate of either [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47417419/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-failed-resolution-of-landroid-support-v4-view-k) or [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43320496/noclassdeffounderror-android-support-v4-animation-animatorcompathelper)

Comment: I will do so... But this is definetly not a duplicate of the from you mentioned posts. Otherwise I wouldnt post this one. I've seen those already... But still want to thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I had problems with

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method isCtrlPressed(Landroid/view/KeyEvent;)
```

and with

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/view/KeyEventCompat
```

I wanted to help u and show u how i managed to solve these problems.

**I use:**

```
 compileSdkVersion 27
 minSdkVersion 21
 targetSdkVersion 27
 versionName '2.6'
 versionCode 8
 buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
```

I needed just to remove all old support dependencies from the gradle (for example: com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0).
And then add those two lines:

```
- implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'

- implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
```